# If there is any way to determine a given integrand without calculation

Tags: integration, statistics, moment-generating-functions

Here I have a moment generating function,
$M_X(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{te^u} e^{- \frac{u^2}{2}} du$

I want to prove it does not exist for any t. But it seems to be impossible to directly solve this integrand.

I know that as $u \to \infty$, $te^u - \frac{u^2}{2} \to \infty$ because exponential term goes much faster than square. However, I don't know how to formally prove this, any help or hint is welcome

Comment: $t=0$ gives the classic Gaussian integral, with $M(0)=1$.

Comment: Thanks, is the next step proving there is no neighborhood of h containing t = 0?

Comment: I’m unsure, but note also that for $t\le0,te^u-u^2/2\to-\infty$ as $u\to\infty$. I assume this moment generating function comes from somewhere sensible, so I expect, but can’t confirm, that it does exist for certain values of $t$.

Comment: If you want moments try characteristic function (it not t).